# Is there a way to copy files directly between two Android devices on the same wifi network?

Tags: wi-fi, sync, file-transfer

I now have a *Samsung Galaxy S* Android phone running Froyo 2.2.1 and an *Archos 101* Android tablet - also running Froyo.

**Both are 'connected' to the same home network via wifi.**

Is there a method by which I can **copy files directly between the two devices** using Wifi?

Bluetooth is also an option, but since I want to copy a lot of thumbnail images, I think this is too slow.

---

**UPDATE**

*The solution I choose:*

I managed to copy files using the **ftp** protocal , using **swiFTP** as ftp server on my Archos table, and using **Ghost Commander** on my Samsung phone.

If you want to try something similar: you might look at my comments to the accepted answer on my other question: **[question about a 550 error I received during my initial ftp testing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/what-does-the-message-550-invalid-name-or-chroot-violation-mean/7195#7195)** in order to see what I had to do to make it running.

Comment: Now a days, in 2018, you can also use NFC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be multiple options available. With a relevant internet search there is an application called **[Bump](http://bu.mp/)** which shares files by simply bumping both devices together. I'm not sure if it does it over wifi if available or only does it over 3G.

There is another option where you can set up an ftp server on the device using an application called **SwiFTP** which is not being maintained anymore but the last update was June 2010. You can install this on one device and use ES File Explorer on the other device to compress and upload the file it using the FTP option.

A third option would be use **[Hoccer](http://hoccer.com/)** which probably uses their service as dropbox does, though I can't be 100% sure.

I'd personally recommend the ftp solution since that seems the most straight forward and you get to ensure that you have a direct connection.

Comment: I managed to install swiFTP on my Archos table, and using Droid commander on my phone, managed to copy files over and from. Thanks for the suggestion and pointing me to swiFTP.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using [DropBox](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dropbox.android&feature=search_result).  The interface let's you upload or download files on an Android device.  Additionally you can manage the files from any computer with DropBox installed on it.  I've been a big fan of using DropBox on my Droid 1 :)

Comment: great suggestion, but wouldnt this be slower than bluetooth because it has to upload to dropbox first and then to the other android device? as far as im aware the LAN speed bonus only works with other PCs on the network.

Comment: Dropbox has a "LAN sync" feature but I don't know if the Android client uses it.

Comment: Ever tried to upload hundreds of small images using DropBox ? And even than, I want to 'drop' them into the same folder on the other device. At the moment I zipped the files, uploaded them to Dropbox ( since the file was 20 mb , this took some time ) and have to download them onto the other device. I just think there should be a better and easier way to do this kind of stuff ( e.g. like an ftp program under Windows ).

Comment: Edelcom, there is a Samba app that may work (as in i havent tried between phones, only between phone and pc) https://market.android.com/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba

Comment: @jayrox true, it would have to "go to the cloud" first. @edelcom good point, I didn't realize you were doing so many files at once.  You could setup an ftp server on one device and then a ftp client on the other?

Answer (score 3):

How about good old FTP?

There are a lot of ftp clients (some filemanagers support it, too) and also some server apps (e.g. SwiFTP).

Answer (score 1):

[WiFi Direct](http://www.wi-fi.org/Wi-Fi_Direct.php) is supposed to allow device to device communication. It is a new standard that should be showing up on wifi device soon (not sure when manufacturers will be supporting this). Here is a [list](http://www.wi-fi.org/search_products.php?search=1&advanced=1&lang=en&filter_company_id=&filter_category_id=&filter_subcategory=&filter_cid=&date_from=&date_to=&selected_certifications%5B%5D=50&x=62&y=10) of devices that have been certified, not all phones. My guess is that when an app is released that takes advantage of this, there will be news on [Engadget](http://engadget.com) or some other place.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it's not the connection a such which was the problem - both devices are connected to a home or business wi-fi netwerk. It was the program I could use to transfer the files ( as you can see in my edited question ).

Answer (score 0):

**ES file explorer.** This app lets you send any size file over bluetooth, wifi(hotspot or local wifi) etc. Very easy to use, just connect both to same wifi hotspot, select the files to send

(OTHER PERSON(s) MUST HAVE ES FILE EXPLORER OPEN)

and press send, or share (the device share menu) and then select via LAN with the ES icon.

You can send file to multiple people at once

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 you can do this from Google's "Files" app directly. It has simple "send" and "receive" buttons and sets up peer-to-peer WiFi temporarily and securely with zero configuration hassle.

Answer (score -1):

Brilliant app this - [Sharable](http://www.sharable.in). All others require internet and data costs - including Bump. Also there is no way you could transfer huge files (full length videos or high quality clips) via other apps. Cross Platform support is amazing. Android, ioS, Mac and PC all supported. Pretty fast as well.

Comment: You have posted the same answer in different questions. Are you affiliated with Shareable? Please note that you have to disclose any affiliation with the mentioned App as per our FAQ.