# What does the message: 550 Invalid name or chroot violation mean?

Tags: ftp

I am trying to establih an Ftp connection between my Archos tablet and my Galaxy phone.

I am using the swiFTP server program on my Archos.

I am able to connect to the Archos from the phone using an TPP client but when I try to copy any file Ireceive the message  '550 Invaid name or chroot violation'.

Can anyone explain what this means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a pretty common problem.

One of the comments in the second link says that you need to change `/sdcard` to `/mnt/sdcard`.  Apparently Android 2.2 changed the way the SDCard is mounted and the error you're receiving comes from `/sdcard` being a symbolic link in 2.2 rather than an absolute path.

- http://code.google.com/p/swiftp/issues/detail?id=86
- http://code.google.com/p/swiftp/updates/list

Comment: @HonnyP: `/mnt/sdcard` did not work. Looking at the links you put in you answer, I decided to try `/` as 'Stay within folder'in swiFTP. Once I did that, I could connect to the Archos, and even more, could change folder. On the Archos I had to change to `/mnt/storage` before I was able to copy files ( the `/sdcard` looks to be a symbolic link to `/mnt/storage` on the Archos 101. Thanks for you help, it really made me look at the correct place to find the solution.

Comment: @Edelcom - No problem, glad I could help!