# Sync mp3s between 2 android devices?

Tags: sync, mp3

I've a galaxy and a Samsung tablet. I download many mp3s on the tablet and I'd like to be able to sync them with the phone and vice versa. Any app for this?

I am talking about lots of files, so Dropbox and Google drive are not what I have in mind. The I'd like something that works over wifi

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Google Music](http://music.google.com) if it's available in your country. It allows you to sync 20.000 music files for free. Or even more if you pay.

Comment: Google music doesn't let me upload music straight from device!

Answer (score 0):

Any file syncing service like Google Drive or Dropbox should do the trick, I believe.

Install the apps on both devices and move the music files to a folder from within the apps.

Comment: That could do. The problem is that they won't sync straight away, but only when I try to open the file. This is bad for data plan reasons and because I use the tube a lot.

Comment: Do you prefer that they sync right away but ONLY on WiFi? Google Drive has an option to auto-update ONLY on WiFi. That should suffice.

Comment: Also see - http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/is-there-a-way-to-copy-files-directly-between-two-android-devices-on-the-same-wi

Comment: Also, WiFi Direct might be a good idea if your devices support it - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer