# How do I transfer media from a Mac to Android?

Tags: file-transfer, media-player, macos

Please help me with this problem, thanks

Comment: This depends on your device. Sometimes your phone may come with software or you can use ADB. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More details would definately be nice. I can think of a few very nice options that would work over wifi.

[Airdroid2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) would let you upload and download files over your browser pretty handily, though a web interface. It does a load of other things too (like act as a filemanager, and let you do things on your phone like send texts from a webui)

[image]

Another alternative would be [pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/) - it lets you send and recieve files up to 25 mb. Like airdroid, it uses a webui on the PC side (or extentions, which are well worth getting IMO) , and [an app on the phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android&hl=en)

You could also use a sync tool like [dropbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Dropbox,%20Inc.&hl=en) or (my current favourite) [bitorrent sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bittorrent.sync) to expose a folder and download files from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an app called [Android File Transfer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/fr.mlog.androidwifitransfert), where you connect you device to your computer through USB and then you can just drag the files into the application. They will be transfered in a matter of seconds!

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty solutions for that. Unfortunately, you didn't specify the options: WiFi? Bluetooth? USB only? Other means?

A first check should bring you to our nice [file-transfer tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/file-transfer/info), linking to questions already having answers on this topic:

- [How can I send a file wirelessly without bluetooth or a Wi-Fi network in ICS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/19985/16575)
- [How can I transfer photos to my Android Jelly Bean device while preserving the original timestamp?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35580/16575)

Also, the "Related" section of your question (to the right, if you use a web browser) has some pointers. And of course there are already several questions tagged [file-transfer](/questions/tagged/file-transfer) (just click on the tag): [Is there a way to copy files directly between two Android devices on the same wifi network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6961/16575) would be one example.

If WiFi is an option, you might want to take a look at [Airdroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.sand.airdroid). That's an app you install on your Android device, start it, and it gives you an URL to type into your browser on your Mac. From there, you can manage your device easily: copy files to and from, check the call log, write an SMS, and much more.

If your device (which you did not mention) has an SDCard, you could also unmount that, put it into a card reader, and attach that to your Mac. Then copy the files to the card, safely unmount, and put it back into your Android device.

For more/other options, please follow the links above – or use the search box :)

Answer (score -1):

Yep if you don't want to use a USB use [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com/). Online file sharing from computer to whatever device:

Make an account then sign in on the computer. Upload the desired files.
When that is done simply download the app aptly named dropbox. Sign in the download the file on your device.

This only takes a few minutes and you could do this with any file. From music to video. From a word document to an APK. Even files that your computer doesnt understand (maybe a file only compatible with macs or phones)

If you dont have an internet connection via 3g then use your home or friends WiFi. You get something like 5 GB extra for doing simple tasks like linking your accounts.

All of your legal illegal files are completely safe. Only you and a peeping tom over your shoulder can see your files. There is no file size limit. This is better than usb because your files will forever be backed up on drop box unless you delete them.

Comment: Common..Google it lol. Ergh make an account then sign in on the computer. "Upload" the desired files. When that is done simply download the app aptly named dropbox. Sign in the download the file on your device. This only takes a few minutes and you could do this with any file. From music to video. From a word document to an APK. Even files that your computer doesnt understand (maybe a file only compatible with macs or iphones)

Comment: ...and from 0 to 2 GB. Don't forget the limits. With that little details given, how can you tell OP even has a data connection on the Android device? Or WiFi for that? And what the limits of the data plan are? How much data should be transfered? Or whether there's a firewall blocking access to Dropbox? Or whether it's sensitive data ("media" could involve very personal photos) OP wouldn't want to trust to the cloud? With the device next to my computer, why should I use a cloud service at all? What's the pros, the cons? We like some quality answers here, common :)

Comment: If you dont have an internet connection via 3g then use your home or friends wifi. You get something like 5 extra gig for doing simple tasks like linking your accounts. All of your legal / illegal files are completely safe. Only you and a peeping tom over your shoulder can see your files. There is no file size limit. This is better than usb because your files will forever be backed up on drop box unless you delete them

Comment: You can't say "your files are completely safe," given Dropbox's poor security record. This is the company that once set up the site so that *any* password would work to log into any account.

Comment: I wouldn't trust them with sensitive data either. AFAIK there's no end-to-end encryption; though *Dropbox* claims to store your data encrypted, *they* could always read it (and so could anybody with the necessary "power", if you know what I mean (you've read the news the past 7 months, I guess)).